# Akka: how to make number of actors in balancing pool relative to thread pool size

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

For an Actor class encompassing a key computation in my application, I am spawning a bunch of actors behind a router:

```
val concurrency = 4 // to be replaced by something dynamic
val ahoCorasick = AppActorSystem.system.actorOf(MyActorClass.props(ldb)
                                         .withRouter(BalancingPool(nrOfInstances = concurrency)), 
                                          name = "foo")
```

How can I get the number of Actor instances relative to the number of cores, or to the size of the thread pool that applies to the actor system? e.g. one Actor per core, or a number of actors equal to the supplied thread pool size? (might also define a thread pool specific to these actors).

Comment: [pool size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getPoolSize()) and [number of cpu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29)

Comment: I doubt about the point of the question. Your code already contains `nrOfInstances = concurrency`. Are your looking for how to get number of CPU cores on the system?

Comment: Of course the point is to replace that constant number. With an Akka thread pool's size (or number of cores).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to get number of threads from your Akka config (`reference.conf` or `application.conf`). Here is the reference [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html) that explains how it's configured. You can have a custom dispatcher or a default one, so the best thing is to not blindly use the code below but to understand which dispatcher you are actually using.

You could do something like this:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}

val conf = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("akka.actor.default-dispatcher.fork-join-executor")

def getThreadConf(conf: Config): (Int, Int, Int) = {
  val parallelismFactor = conf.getInt("parallelism-factor")
  val parallelismMin = conf.getInt("parallelism-min")
  val parallelismMax = conf.getInt("parallelism-max")
  (parallelismFactor, parallelismMin, parallelismMax)
}

println(getThreadConf(conf))
val system = ActorSystem()
println(getThreadConf(system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.actor.default-dispatcher.fork-join-executor")))
```

By default you get:

```
factor: 3, min: 8, max: 64
```

Check the name of dispatcher you are using or set one explicitly with `val myActor = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("my-dispatcher"), "myactor1")`

Comment: Note that if you are using `BalancingPool` (from doc): "The configuration parameter trumps the constructor arguments. This means that if you provide nrOfInstances during instantiation they will be ignored if the router is defined in the configuration file for the actor being used.". http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/index.html#akka.routing.BalancingPool.  So I would prefer to configure it via `application.conf` rather than in code.